# layout problem in samsung galaxy tab application

Tags: android

Hi friends 
I am creating application for samsung galaxy tab while giving fill_parent the layout is not filling full screen left side and right side black screen appear can anybody tell what is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I giving support screen tag in android manifest file I got